# Why does my ceiling fan turn on by itself?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have an Eliza Hugger Atlas fan.  The only problem is that it turns on randomly by itself at night.  Doesn't seem like the exact same time, but sometimes I wake up in the night and it's on.  I see a lot of comments about the neighbors code, etc.  I'm not an expert to be able to take it down from ceiling to change codes.  I can't find any manual on Atlas site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you still have the paper manual the fan came with?

Comment: How is the fan wired? How do you normally control it? Feel free to [edit] your question so that it's written in a way that people who do _not_ live at your house will have a full understanding of the situation you're facing. I'm sure this is 100% clear & obvious to you, but none of us are you...

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell for sure why the fan switches on on its own, but one possibility is that there is a different remote control within range, e.g. a neighbour's as you already allude to.

Most likely you do *not* have climb to the fan and open it.

You can change the frequency of the remote control following the description in the installation manual. The fan's receiver will automatically adjust to the new frequency. For the automatic learning and calibration to start you have to *cycle the power to the fan off and then on*. If there is no main switch in the room that does this (the fan is permanently powered) then use the breaker to cut off and restore the power. If you need help cycling the power or finding the breaker, leave a comment below.

From the manufacturer's site download the installation  manual:

http://www.matthewsfanco.com/index.php?page=eliza

Here are the pertinent excerpts:

[image]

and here:

[image]